# Linux .sh auto set local variables empty when echo

Tags: linux, shell, sh

./run.sh:

```
1. cp=warmonger-1.0.0.jar
2. cmmd="java -server -D64 -Xms200m -Xmx200m 
     -Dlog4j.configurationFile=$WARMONGER_HOME/etc/log4j2.xml
     -classpath $cp warmonger.agent.WarmongerAgentApp"
3. echo $cmmd
```

execute results:

```
dataq.agent.DataqAgentApp -Xmx200m 
  -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/warmonger/etc/log4j2.xml 
  -classpath warmonger-1.0.0.jar
```

"warmonger.agent.WarmongerAgentApp" not appear.

I means if remove echo, java will be throw an exception: Couldn't find main class

Comment: warmonger-1.0.0.jar it is already printing? What do you mean cp is not appearing?

Comment: The changes `cp=warmonger-1.0.0.jar` makes to the environment are lost once the shell finishes.

Comment: @kiranBiradar cp's  after not print, or remove echo, this command is wrong.

Comment: Commands you want to execute shouldn't be put into string variables at all; better practice is to use an array or a function -- see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). There are lots of example scripts for starting Java programs that do this, granted -- but if you read the link you'll see why the pattern creates fragile, bug-prone code.

Answer (score 0):

You won't see `$cp` when you `echo $cmmd`, because the shell substitutes the value of the `cp` parameter (`warmonger-1.0.0.jar`) in the assignment to `cmmd`.

You can escape the dollar sign, or use single quotes if you don't want the shell to expand the parameter.

Comment: sorry, i am  wrong.  i wanna replace cp and execute that jar,  but java Couldn't find main class .

Answer (score 0):

Your shell script is CR-LF terminated (DOS/Windows ends of lines). Thus, from `bash` point of view, the `cp` variable contains `warmonger-1.0.0.jar<CR>` (notice the trailing `<CR>`).

When you `echo` the content of the `cp` variable, `<CR>` is echoed too which puts the cursor at the beginning of the line (CR = carriage return). `echo` then prints the remaining of the arguments at the beginning of the line.

You can see it in your output:

- "java -server -D64 -Xms200m -Xmx200m" is overwritten with "warmonger.agent.WarmongerAgentApp"
- which, in turn, is overwritten by some other command output ("dataq.agent.Dataq")

Solution: turn your DOS/Windows text file into a UNIX one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39527986/7233423).